# Click event count of the facebook like button(iframe from fb) in parent page(my page), not 'liked' count I need click count

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Is it possible to get the javascript click event for the facebook like button? Actually in my page I have just added

```
<a id='Facebook' class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
```

When I clicked on this anchor tag it is not taking the click event in my page, click is happening in the facebook that contained inside the iframe loaded inside the anchor tag by facebook. I am using click event js as

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) { }
```

How may times the fb like button clicked, that information is what I am looking for. But the click event itself not firing in my page. Please help me.

Mbn

Answer (score 0):

By using facebook javascript SDK with XFBML/HTML5 implementation of like button, you can subscribe to events using `FB.Event.subscribe`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

If you want to stick with iframe(third party), only way to track will be using analytics data provided by facebook. developers.facebook.com/docs/insights

Comment: Thanks for your response. For my case I need the click count of the facebook like button or tweet button. It may be twitter fb pin it ect. So I need a click count of these buttons. Inside Iframe click is not getting on parent page because Iframe is handling by the third parties ie., facebook, twitter ect...Please help me for this

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is tracking the click rights?. Not sure you can do this by using iframe. You can achieve this without iframe. eg: for twitter you can use Web Intents https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events

Comment: Exactly, I want to track the clicks. Whatever the buttons or links that the clients can manage. So it may be facebook like or some other. So issue is with that iframe only. fb like iframe and twitter tweet iframe. Thanks for your response.

Comment: It is impossible to track events  when using iframes(third party).If you want to stick with iframe only way to track will using analytics provided by fabook/twitter. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/